# Apache ServletFIleUpload freezes

Tags: apache, servlets, apache-commons-fileupload

This perplexes me. In the following code not even "1" is being printed out in the console. If i place a breakpoint (using eclipse) in the first system.out line, the debugger never exits it. No exceptions thrown. I also tried passing a null argument to SFU's constructor to force it to throw an exception, but nothing happened.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {                          
        System.out.println("1");

        try {                               
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();             
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new ServletException(e);
        }

        System.out.println("2");
}
```

And the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>File Upload</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="loadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <input type="file" name="myFile" id="myFile" /> <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload" id="upload" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try remove **"throws ServletException, IOException"** from

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
```

and change

```
   try {                               
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();             
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new ServletException(e);
        }
```

to:

```
   try {                               
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(); 
        //... rest of code

        } catch (FileUploadException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

Add any other exceptions to the catch clause, don't throw them. That's why you don't see what the error is about

Also noticed that the name of your form action is **loadFile**
does this correspond to your Servlet name? Servlets usually have a capitalized first letter ! My suspicion is that this is the real problem, you're sending a post request to a servlet the server can't find.